# How to get the ConsumerRecord object in StreamListener Consumer code

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I wanted to enable the manual commit for my consumer and for that i have below code + configuration. Here i am trying to manually commit the offset in case signIn client throws exception and till manually comitting offet itw works fine but with this code the message which failed to process is not being consumed again so for that what i want to do is calling seek method and consume same failed offset again -

> consumer.seek(newTopicPartition(atCommunityTopic,communityFeed.partition()),communityFeed.offset());

**But the actual problem is here how do i get partition and offset details from. If somehow i can get ConsumerRecord object along with message then it will work.**

> spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.atcommnity.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false

And Below is the consumer code through StreamListener

```
        @StreamListener(ConsumerConstants.COMMUNITY_IN)
        public void handleCommFeedConsumer(
                @Payload Account consumerRecords,
                @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER) Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                @Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
            

            consumerRecords.forEach(communityFeed -> {
                try{
                   
                AccountClient.signIn(
                        AccountIn.builder()
                                .Id(atCommunityEvent.getId())
                                .build());
                log.debug("Calling  Client for Id : "
                        + communityEvent.getId());
                
                }catch(RuntimeException ex){
                    log.info("");
                    //consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(communityTopic,communityFeed.partition()),communityFeed.offset());
                    return;
                }
                acknowledgment.acknowledge();
            });
        

           
        }
```

Comment: @StreamListener and annotation-based programming model has been deprecate for a very long time and is already removed from the main branch. Please upgrade to functional programing model - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programming_model

Comment: It will be difficult for us to migrate to functional approach at this point of time without breaking the other consumer which are already there for very long time and and using streamListener. we are already using functional programming model in other services but as this is a lagacy app we still need to go with old way.

Comment: You should not perform seeks yourself; the default error handler will do the seeks for you if you throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#consumer-record-metadata

`@Header(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID) int partition`

`@Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset`

**IMPORTANT**

Seeking the consumer yourself might not do what you want because the container may already have other records after this one; it's best to throw an exception and the error handler will do the seeks for you.